# How do I get value of a checkboxes of a row in a table JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this might be a stupid question but I need to get values of checked checkboxes of a specific row.

```
<form method="POST" action="flight_cart.php">
    <table>
        <tr id=1>
            <td><input id="foodType" type="checkbox" value="Burger">Burger</input></td>
            <td><input id="extras" type="checkbox" value="jalapeno">Jalapeno</input></td>
            <td><input id="extras" type="checkbox" value="mustard">Mustard</input></td>
            <td><input id="extras" type="checkbox" value="Chili">Chili Sauce</input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=2>
            <td><input id="foodType" type="checkbox" value="Sandwich">Sandwich</input></td>
            <td><input id="extras" type="checkbox" value="jalapeno">Jalapeno</input></td>
            <td><input id="extras" type="checkbox" value="mustard">Mustard</input></td>
            <td><input id="extras" type="checkbox" value="Chili">Chili Sauce</input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=3>
            <td><input id="foodType" type="checkbox" value="Sub">Sub</input></td>
            <td><input id="extras" type="checkbox" value="jalapeno">Jalapeno</input></td>
            <td><input id="extras" type="checkbox" value="mustard">Mustard</input></td>
            <td><input id="extras" type="checkbox" value="Chili">Chili Sauce</input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><button type="submit">Add to Order</td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

So basically, I want users to be able to pick for example: Burger with jalapeno, Sandwich with jalapeno, mustard, and chili, and sub with chili only. And storing them into an array so I can pass it to cart page. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? and try to `reuse` the those extras. change your design.

Comment: user can select only one extra with each foodtype?

Comment: First you have to create a unique id for each checkbox.

Comment: Darren, did any of the following answers help you, or are you still facing problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might be what you are looking for or it should give you a good idea about how to solve your problem

Note: It is not good practice to have multiple elements with the same `Id`. Use `class` for that

This example also checks that you have selected a `foodtype` before it pushes the data into the array.

```js
$("table button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var food = [];
  $("table tr").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".foodType").prop("checked") == true) {
      var values = $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
      }).get();
      food.push(values)
    }
  })
  console.log(food)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <table>
    <tr id=1>
      <td><input class="foodType" type="checkbox" value="Burger">Burger</input>
      </td>
      <td><input class="extras" type="checkbox" value="jalapeno">Jalapeno</input>
      </td>
      <td><input class="extras" type="checkbox" value="mustard">Mustard</input>
      </td>
      <td><input class="extras" type="checkbox" value="Chili">Chili Sauce</input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=2>
      <td><input class="foodType" type="checkbox" value="Sandwich">Sandwich</input>
      </td>
      <td><input class="extras" type="checkbox" value="jalapeno">Jalapeno</input>
      </td>
      <td><input class="extras" type="checkbox" value="mustard">Mustard</input>
      </td>
      <td><input class="extras" type="checkbox" value="Chili">Chili Sauce</input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=3>
      <td><input class="foodType" type="checkbox" value="Sub">Sub</input>
      </td>
      <td><input class="extras" type="checkbox" value="jalapeno">Jalapeno</input>
      </td>
      <td><input class="extras" type="checkbox" value="mustard">Mustard</input>
      </td>
      <td><input class="extras" type="checkbox" value="Chili">Chili Sauce</input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="submit">Add to Order</td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use code

```
$("tr[id='1']").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked")
```

Comment: Dhaval, this only provide him with a way to check what checkbox has been checked. But there is way more to the question than just that

Answer (score 0):

Just add some id to form,

```
var choices=[];
$("#formId input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
   choices.push($(this)[0].value);
});
```

and you will get array of all selected checkboxes in form.